# How can I create a Zotero citation format of [NameYear] without the et al appearing?

Tags: xml, bibliography, citations, csl

I am new to Zotero and to Citation Style Language (CSL). I would like to modify a style to permit a citation style with the format [NameYear], where 'Name' is the family name of the first author and 'Year' is the publication year. I can easily adapt another similar style of the format 'author-date' type, however I have been unable to remove the 'et al.' that appears in this example below:

[King et al.2011]

What I am trying to get is [King2011] in this case. I want to ignore all other authors for the purposes of this citation.

I also use the same format as the start of the bibliography entry, which currently reads as:

"[King et al.2011]  R.R. King et al., Band gap-voltage offset and energy production in next-generation multijunction solar cells. Prog. Photovolt: Res. Appl. 19, 797–812 (2011)."

And here again I want the start of this bibliographic entry to read simply "[King2011]".

(Note: I do understand how to control the full author list in the bibliographic entry, which is displayed above as "R.R. King et al.", so I am not having any problem for this part.)

If anyone has insight on how to remove the "et al." from this author "list" in the citation (or simply just insert the family name of the first author), I would very much appreciate any assistance you can provide!

(I'm using Zotero 5.0.96.2)

This is the CSL file I am trying to adapt, based on the Elsevier Harvard (titles) file. I added the macros "author-short" and "citation_text", and modified the citation and bibliography sections.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<style xmlns="http://purl.org/net/xbiblio/csl" class="in-text" version="1.0" demote-non-dropping-particle="never" default-locale="en-US">
  <!-- This style was edited with the Visual CSL Editor (https://editor.citationstyles.org/visualEditor/) -->
  <info>
    <title>Modified_Elsevier_Harvard_titles</title>
    <id>http://www.zotero.org/styles/cev_elsevier_harvard_titles</id>
    <link href="http://www.zotero.org/styles/cev_elsevier_harvard_titles" rel="self"/>
    <link href="http://www.zotero.org/styles/ecology-letters" rel="template"/>
    <link href="http://www.elsevier.com/journals/biological-conservation/0006-3207/guide-for-authors#68000" rel="documentation"/>
    <author>
      <name>David Kaplan</name>
      <email>david.kaplan@ird.fr</email>
    </author>
    <contributor>
      <name>Simon Kornblith</name>
      <email>simon@simonster.com</email>
    </contributor>
    <contributor>
      <name>Bruce D'Arcus</name>
    </contributor>
    <contributor>
      <name>Curtis M. Humphrey</name>
    </contributor>
    <contributor>
      <name>Richard Karnesky</name>
      <email>karnesky+zotero@gmail.com</email>
      <uri>http://arc.nucapt.northwestern.edu/Richard_Karnesky</uri>
    </contributor>
    <contributor>
      <name>Sebastian Karcher</name>
    </contributor>
    <category citation-format="author-date"/>
    <category field="biology"/>
    <category field="generic-base"/>
    <updated>2021-10-20T22:57:37+00:00</updated>
    <rights license="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">This work is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 License</rights>
  </info>
  <macro name="container">
    <choose>
      <if type="chapter paper-conference" match="any">
        <text term="in" prefix=", " suffix=": "/>
        <names variable="editor translator" delimiter=", " suffix=", ">
          <name name-as-sort-order="all" sort-separator=", " initialize-with="." delimiter=", " delimiter-precedes-last="always"/>
          <label form="short" text-case="capitalize-first" prefix=" (" suffix=")"/>
        </names>
        <group delimiter=", ">
          <text variable="container-title" text-case="title"/>
          <text variable="collection-title" text-case="title"/>
        </group>
      </if>
      <else-if type="bill book graphic legal_case legislation motion_picture report song" match="any">
        <group prefix=", " delimiter=", ">
          <text variable="container-title"/>
          <text variable="collection-title"/>
        </group>
      </else-if>
      <else>
        <group prefix=". " delimiter=", ">
          <text variable="container-title" form="short"/>
          <text variable="collection-title"/>
        </group>
      </else>
    </choose>
  </macro>
  <macro name="author">
    <names variable="author">
      <name et-al-min="3" et-al-use-first="1" initialize-with="."/>
      <label form="short" prefix=" (" suffix=")" text-case="capitalize-first"/>
      <substitute>
        <names variable="editor"/>
        <names variable="translator"/>
        <text macro="title"/>
      </substitute>
    </names>
  </macro>
  <macro name="author-short">
    <names variable="author">
      <name form="short" delimiter="" and="symbol" delimiter-precedes-et-al="never" delimiter-precedes-last="never" et-al-min="1" et-al-use-first="1" initialize-with=". " sort-separator=""/>
      <substitute>
        <names variable="editor"/>
        <names variable="translator"/>
        <choose>
          <if type="bill book graphic legal_case legislation motion_picture report song" match="any">
            <text variable="title" form="short" font-style="italic"/>
          </if>
          <else>
            <text variable="title" form="short" quotes="true"/>
          </else>
        </choose>
      </substitute>
    </names>
  </macro>
  <macro name="access">
    <choose>
      <if variable="DOI">
        <text variable="DOI" prefix="https://doi.org/"/>
      </if>
      <else-if type="webpage post-weblog" match="any">
        <group delimiter=" ">
          <text value="URL"/>
          <text variable="URL"/>
          <group prefix="(" suffix=").">
            <text term="accessed" suffix=" "/>
            <date variable="accessed">
              <date-part name="month" form="numeric" suffix="."/>
              <date-part name="day" suffix="."/>
              <date-part name="year" form="short"/>
            </date>
          </group>
        </group>
      </else-if>
    </choose>
  </macro>
  <macro name="title">
    <choose>
      <if type="report thesis" match="any">
        <text variable="title"/>
        <group prefix=" (" suffix=")" delimiter=" ">
          <text variable="genre"/>
          <text variable="number" prefix="No. "/>
        </group>
      </if>
      <else-if type="bill book graphic legal_case legislation motion_picture report song speech" match="any">
        <text variable="title"/>
        <text macro="edition" prefix=", "/>
      </else-if>
      <else-if type="webpage">
        <text variable="title"/>
        <text value="WWW Document" prefix=" [" suffix="]"/>
      </else-if>
      <else>
        <text variable="title"/>
      </else>
    </choose>
  </macro>
  <macro name="publisher">
    <group delimiter=", ">
      <text variable="publisher"/>
      <text variable="publisher-place"/>
    </group>
  </macro>
  <macro name="event">
    <choose>
      <if variable="event">
        <text term="presented at" text-case="capitalize-first" suffix=" "/>
        <text variable="event"/>
      </if>
    </choose>
  </macro>
  <macro name="issued">
    <choose>
      <if variable="issued">
        <date variable="issued">
          <date-part name="year"/>
        </date>
      </if>
      <else>
        <text term="no date" form="short"/>
      </else>
    </choose>
  </macro>
  <macro name="edition">
    <group delimiter=" ">
      <choose>
        <if is-numeric="edition">
          <number variable="edition" form="ordinal"/>
        </if>
        <else>
          <text variable="edition" suffix="."/>
        </else>
      </choose>
      <text value="ed"/>
    </group>
  </macro>
  <macro name="locators">
    <choose>
      <if type="article-journal article-magazine article-newspaper" match="any">
        <group prefix=" " delimiter=", ">
          <group>
            <text variable="volume"/>
          </group>
          <text variable="page"/>
        </group>
      </if>
      <else-if type="bill book graphic legal_case legislation motion_picture report song thesis" match="any">
        <group delimiter=", " prefix=". ">
          <text macro="event"/>
          <text macro="publisher"/>
        </group>
      </else-if>
      <else-if type="chapter paper-conference" match="any">
        <group delimiter=", " prefix=". ">
          <text macro="event"/>
          <text macro="publisher"/>
          <group>
            <label variable="page" form="short" suffix=" "/>
            <text variable="page"/>
          </group>
        </group>
      </else-if>
      <else-if type="patent">
        <text variable="number" prefix=". "/>
      </else-if>
    </choose>
  </macro>
  <macro name="citation_text">
    <group>
      <text macro="author-short"/>
      <text value=""/>
      <text macro="issued"/>
      <group delimiter=" ">
        <label variable="locator" form="short"/>
        <text variable="locator"/>
      </group>
    </group>
  </macro>
  <citation et-al-min="3" et-al-use-first="1" disambiguate-add-givenname="true" disambiguate-add-year-suffix="true" collapse="year" cite-group-delimiter=", ">
    <sort>
      <key macro="author"/>
      <key macro="issued" sort="descending"/>
    </sort>
    <layout delimiter="; " prefix="[" suffix="]">
      <text macro="citation_text"/>
    </layout>
  </citation>
  <bibliography hanging-indent="true" entry-spacing="0" line-spacing="1">
    <sort>
      <key macro="author"/>
      <key macro="issued" sort="descending"/>
    </sort>
    <layout>
      <text macro="citation_text" prefix="[" suffix="]  "/>
      <group suffix=".">
        <text macro="author" suffix=","/>
        <group prefix=" ">
          <text macro="title"/>
          <text macro="container"/>
          <text macro="locators"/>
        </group>
        <text macro="issued" prefix=" (" suffix=")"/>
      </group>
    </layout>
  </bibliography>
</style>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.